# Dynamic $in operator based on a variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a variable and based on that value I would like to change the $in operator within mongo query.

My code -

```
var query_op = "$in";
if (criteria.group === "abc")
{
var query_op = "$nin";
}
```

And then

```
var query = Model.find(
                {
                    _id:
                        {
                            $in: query_op 
                        }
                        ,
...........................
});
```

Would it be possible to use in this way?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in JavaScript you can dynamically define object's key using square brackets, try:

```
var query_op = "$in";
if (criteria.group === "abc")
{
    var query_op = "$nin";
}

var query = Model.find(
            {
                _id:
                    {
                        [query_op]: listOfIds
                    }
});
```